# SQL to count number of duplicates in a column with GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have a table named `table_a` that looks as follows:

```
Color   Person   Shape
blue    Jane     circle
orange  Bob      square
blue    Sally    rectangle
yellow  Ted      circle
green   Bill     diamond
yellow  Barry    circle
blue    Sally    hexagon
blue    Mary     circle
```

I would like to get a count of the number of people (`person` column) using the same color, as follows:

```
Color    number_people
blue     3
yellow   2
```

I would like to get the number of people who have the same color.  My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT
  Color, COUNT(*) as number_people
FROM
  from table_a
GROUP BY Color
HAVING number_people > 1
```

Is this correct?  And, if yes, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want `COUNT(DISTINCT person) as number_people` instead of `COUNT(*)` so that you don't count Sally as 2 people in Blue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  table_a.Color, COUNT(b.primarykey) as number_people
FROM
  from table_a
  join table_a b on (table_primarykey = b.primarykey)
GROUP BY table_a.Color
HAVING number_people > 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `DISTINCT` somewhere?  Also, I'm questioning the need for a `JOIN`.

Comment: test it! how else you gna know tf, i dont have your db infront of me